# Set SVG height through CSS?

Tags: css, html, svg, background-image

Here's my CSS:

```
#social #twitter {
    background-image: url("../img/twitter.svg");
    max-height: 32px;
    max-width: 32px;
}
```

And my HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="social">
    <div id="twitter"></div>
</div>
```

The SVG doesn't scale down to 32x32. The SVG is 512x512. Could someone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add

```
background-size: contain;
```

to the CSS. See the [MDN docu](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-size) for details on `background-size` and the table of supporting browsers and browser versions.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I have another problem though. I have a style for when you hover over it (it fades) but now that I've switched it to SVG it doesn't fade, instead it makes this weird jumpy animation.

Comment: @Fike I think that's a different problem. So create another question for this and set up a fiddle to show your code.